# Extract a specific sheet from several excel workbooks and add to new workbook

Tags: excel, pandas, export-to-excel

I am trying to create a function that;

- gets all excel files in a folder
- reads a specific sheet
- adds that to an excel workbook.

The following function works, however i can't open the file itself as I get a
'Excel cannot open the file ’New.xlsx’ because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.'

I have tried understanding why through lots of key word searches but i cannot figure it. out.

```
def mul_sheet_mul_excel_combiner(path, sheet, newbookname):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    files = []
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if i.endswith('.csv') or i.endswith('.xlsx') or i.endswith('.xls'):
            files.append(i)
    out_path = newbookname+'.xlsx'
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
    n = 0 
    for file in files:
        print(file)
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = sheet, engine='openpyxl')
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(n))
        n +=1
path = "."
sheetname = 0
newbookname = 'New'
mul_sheet_mul_excel_combiner(path, sheetname, newbookname)
```